# Multiple ajax in NodeJS, MongoDB and Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, pug

How can I do multiple ajax without submitting a form.

I am trying to update the data in the database when someone clicks the checkbox and then updating that particular div where the data has been updated in the database. I want to achieve this without reloading the whole page.

I manage to do the first part, but I am stuck in the second part because I don't know how to do multiple ajax requests.

I am using Pug for the front-end, NodeJS for the back-end, and MongoDB for database.

**Schema**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    todos: [
        {
            task: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                required: 'Please Enter your Task',
            },
            dueDate: {
                type: Date,
                default: new Date(+new Date() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            },
            dueTime: String,
            done: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

**routes**

```
router.get('/', catchErrors(todoControllers.todo));
router.post('/',catchErrors(todoControllers.addTodo));
router.put('/todo/:id', catchErrors(todoControllers.checkStatus));
```

**Controller**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.todo = async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (user.todos.length) {
        const updatedUser = await User.aggregate([
            { $unwind: '$todos' },
            { $sort: { 'todos.dueDate': 1 } },
            { $group: { _id: '$_id', todos: { $push: '$todos' } } },
        ]);
        res.render('todos', { updatedUser: updatedUser[0].todos });
    } else {
        res.render('layout');
    }
};

exports.addTodo = async (req, res) => {
    const add = {
        todos: {
            task: req.body.task,
            dueDate: req.body.dueDate,
            dueTime: req.body.dueTime,
        },
    };

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $push: add },
        { new: true }
    ).exec();

    req.flash('success', 'saved');
    res.redirect('/');
};

exports.checkStatus = async (req, res) => {
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { todos: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id } } },
        { $set: { 'todos.$.done': req.body.done } }
    );
};
```

**main.js** (it is the main client-side javascript file)

```
$('.todo--checkbox').change(function () {
    let value = $(this).data('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: `/todo/${value}`,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: { done: this.checked },
    });
});
```

**Pug file**

```
.todos
    if updatedUser
        h5 Task
        each todo in updatedUser
            - let dueDate  = h.moment(todo.dueDate).format("dddd DD MMMM YYYY")
            if !todo.done
                .card
                    .card-content
                        label
                            input(type="checkbox" data-value=todo._id ).todo--checkbox
                            span= `${todo.task} - ${todo._id}`

                        if (dueDate === h.moment(Date.now()).format("dddd DD MMMM YYYY"))
                            p.due--date--time
                                span.material-icons.red-text notifications
                                | Today at #{todo.dueTime}
                        else
                            p.due--date--time
                                span.material-icons notifications
                                | #{dueDate}

       
        h5 Completed 
        each todo in updatedUser
            if todo.done
                .card
                    .card-content
                        label
                            input(type="checkbox" checked data-value=todo._id ).todo--checkbox
                            span= `${todo.task}`
    else 
        br
        h3 No Task
```

I want to update the `.todos` div when anyone checks the checkbox.

How can I use ajax to update `.todos`?